# CloudFormation IAM policy with custom condition string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to build an IAM policy with a resource tag condition. I want the tag to be a parameter to the CloudFormation template. I am using something like this where pCustomTag is passed as a parameter to the CloudFormation stack:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "IAM Role",
  "Parameters": {
    "pCustomTag": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "mycustomtag"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "rEC2IAMProfile": {
      "Properties": {
        "InstanceProfileName": "MY_EC2_PROFILE",
        "Path": "/",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "rIAMRole"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
    },
    "rIAMRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": "MY_EC2_ROLE",
        "PermissionsBoundary": {
          "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/ais-permissions-boundaries"
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore",
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy"
        ],
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ],
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "rSTONITH": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "STONITH",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "rIAMRole"
          }
        ],
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
              ],
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:instance/*"
              },
              "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    ":",
                    [
                      {
                        "Fn::Sub": "\"aws:ResourceTag/${pCustomTag}\""
                      },
                      " \"*\""
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "oTestString": {
      "Description": "Test string",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          ":",
          [
            {
              "Fn::Sub": "\"aws:ResourceTag/${pCustomTag}\""
            },
            " \"*\""
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However it results in syntax error in policy (rSTONITH). The error from CloudFormation is this:

```
Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: abc; Proxy: null)
```

For testing I use the same construct in the outputs section which results in the string I'm looking for.

```
  "Outputs": {
    "oTestString": {
      "Description": "Test string",
      "Value":{
        "Fn::Join": [
          ":", [
            { "Fn::Sub": "\"aws:ResourceTag/${pCustomTag}\"" },
            " \"*\""
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

Any idea why it does not work when using it in resource section (for resource "AWS::IAM::Policy").

Comment: What is the full code and full error message?

Comment: I added the the full code to the post. Changing the condition to the following does not throw error, but the tag is fixed:

`"Condition": {`
`. "StringLike": {`
`.   "aws:ResourceTag/mycustomtag": "*"`
`. }`
`}`

The output (oTestString), although using Fn::Join/Fn::Sub shows the string I am looking for: "aws:ResourceTag/mycustomtag": "*"